# prevent page from scrolling back to top after closing modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any idea how I can prevent page from scrolling back to top of page when modal window is closed? I need it to stay in the same positing as page full of text and you end up losing where you were. I had this working but for some strange reason no longer works.
Thanks.

Page calls a PHP request that goes through a while loop and displays sentences that when clicked shows additional info. This is displayed in the modal window.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{ ?> 
<a  href="#" class="nojump" id="mymodal" onclick="showModal(this)"  
style="font-size:16px;"  title="<? echo  $row ['title']  ?> 
 by
 <? echo $row ['author'] ?>" ><? echo $row ['first_line'] ?> </a>


<script>
  function showModal(el) {
    jQuery("#myModalLabel").text(el.title);
    jQuery("#myModal").modal()
  }

</script>
<script>
  jQuery('a.nojump').click(function(e)
  {
    // Cancel the default action
    e.preventDefault();
  });
</script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">  
         <div class="modal-header">    
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
               <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>  
         <div class="modal-body">   
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>  
         </div>  
         <div class="modal-footer">    
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hapodot/edit?html,js,output) I recreate from the issue it's work correctly nothing strange.

Comment: Sorry. Realise the table is pretty useless info. Have added the while statement that calls the function

Comment: Why you need onclick="showModal(this)" this is wired cause you already have a click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**
I update the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/hapodot/edit?html,js,console,output) here is this what you want?

**HTML:**

```
 <a  href="#myModal" class="nojump" style="font-size:16px;" title="title" data-toggle="modal">click me</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
jQuery('a.nojump').click(function(e) {  
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('do something here')
    });
```